# Postgres Custom Domain Type vs UNIQUE

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

I wan't to be sure that not a empty text can be stored into my table. Therefore I created a domain type:

`CREATE DOMAIN non_empty_text AS TEXT CHECK( VALUE ~ '\S' );` and changed all text types to non_empty_text.

So far so good. But would it be more efficient when I would change the type back to text and create a UNIQUE index and a row with empty values?

Comment: A unique index is something complete different then checking for non-empty values

Comment: Technically yes. But if I create rows which have all forbidden values then these can't be added anymore. Obviously it's horrible ugly xD

Comment: Consider changing your check condition to `VALUE <> ''` to make it faster and easier to read.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut then a VALUE with multiple spaces would be permitted or?

Comment: Yeah, it depends on what you mean by "empty text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You of course need to benchmark this, but offhand, I'd say you should change your approach.

The current domain type logic you have evaluates the string in memory. The second approach requires accessing an index and looking for a block that may or may not be in the cache. Accessing the storage, even if it doesn't happen **all** the time, is so expensive compared to an in-memory operation, that this probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: So it's never a good idea to add UNIQUE indexes if you do not actually really need it!?

Comment: @velop pretty much, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach with the domain is correct.  The alternative with the unique constraint is an interesting idea, but I would consider it premature optimization.